# How can I get pairs of values, where the first is taken from one list and the second from another list?

Tags: python, generator, combinatorics

I want something like the code below, but in a "Pythonic" style or using the standard library:

```
def combinations(a,b):
    for i in a:
        for j in b:
             yield(i,j)
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample input and output? Currently you are creating a pair for each element in `a` and `b`. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

These are not really "combinations" in the sense of combinatorics. These are rather elements from the Cartesian product of `a` and `b`.  The function in the standard library to generate these pairs is [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
for i, j in itertools.product(a, b):
    # Whatever
```

Answer (score 52):

As [Sven said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499327/how-can-i-get-pairs-of-values-where-the-first-is-taken-from-one-list-and-the-se/6499338#6499338), your code is attempting to get all ordered pairs of elements of the lists `a` and `b`. In this case `itertools.product(a,b)` is what you want.

If instead you actually want "combinations", which are all unordered pairs of distinct elements of the list `a`, then you want `itertools.combinations(a,2)`.

```
>>> for pair in itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4],2):
...    print pair
...
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 8):

A nested generator expression will work too:

```
product = ((i, j) for i in a for j in b)
for i, j in product:
    # ...
```

Comment: Not standard library function, but way more pythonic then mine "C"-like version ;-) thanks for providing alternative to itertools.product()

Comment: @Dima: at least you used `yield` ;)

Answer (score 7):

The [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) library has combinatorics functions. Like [Sven stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499327/how-can-i-get-pairs-of-values-where-the-first-is-taken-from-one-list-and-the-se/6499338#6499338), `itertools.product` would be the appropriate function in this case:

```
list(itertools.product('ab', 'cd'))
[('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>>a=[1,2,3]
>>>b=[4,5,6]
>>>zip(a,b)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: I also want (1,5), (1,6), (2,4), (2,6), (3,4), (3,5) in addition to three pairs created by zip....

Comment: Well, although @fransua got a -2 downvote, this is exactly what I needed as a pair. I will upvote your answer.

Answer (score 3):

A question we might ask is whether you want to generate all ordered pairs or all unordered pairs. The nested generator expression provided in the [answer by mhyfritz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499327/how-can-i-get-pairs-of-values-where-the-first-is-taken-from-one-list-and-the-se/6499407#6499407) will give you all ordered pairs.

If you want all *unordered* pairs (that is, (1, 2) and (2, 1) counts as the same pair), then you need to filter out the duplicates. An easy way to do this is to add a conditional to the end of the generator expression like so:

```
myList= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
unorderedPairGenerator = ((x, y) for x in myList for y in myList if y > x)
for pair in unorderedPairGenerator:
    print(pair)
#(1, 2)
#(1, 3)
#(1, 4)
#(1, 5)
#(2, 3)
#(2, 4)
#(2, 5)
#(3, 4)
#(3, 5)
#(4, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create set of pairs (even,odd) combination

```
>>> a = { (i,j) for i in range(0,10,2) for j in range(1,10,2)}  
>>> a
{(4, 7), (6, 9), (0, 7), (2, 1), (8, 9), (0, 3), (2, 5), (8, 5), (4, 9), (6, 7), (2, 9), (8, 1), (6, 3), (4, 1), (4, 5), (0, 5), (2, 3), (8, 7), (6, 5), (0, 1), (2, 7), (8, 3), (6, 1), (4, 3), (0, 9)}

def combinations(lista, listb):
    return { (i,j) for i in lista for j in listb }

>>> combinations([1,3,5,6],[11,21,133,134,443])
{(1, 21), (5, 133), (5, 11), (5, 134), (6, 11), (6, 134), (1, 443), (3, 11), (6, 21), (3, 21), (1, 133), (1, 134), (5, 21), (3, 134), (5, 443), (6, 443), (1, 11), (3, 443), (6, 133), (3, 133)}
```