# Generate a large list of points with no duplicates

Tags: python, list, random, points

I want to create a large list containing 20,000 points in the form of:

```
[[x, y], [x, y], [x, y]]
```

where x and y can be any random integer between 0 and 1000. How would I be able to do this such that there are no duplicate coordinates [x, y]?

Comment: you need random elements in the list ?

Comment: try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499327/is-there-python-way-to-generate-pairs

Comment: As you create a coordinate pair compare back through the list to see if it exists before appending it... Are they integers?

Comment: Yes integers, i have tried appending it to the list and then checking, but it will freeze because i think it might be too slow when it has to check the list if it is there evey time?

Comment: get your [X, Y] as random(0,1000) and *before* appending use *if not [x,y] in MainList: MainList.append([x,y])* the indexing function is faster than comparing each preceding element in python.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a while loop to pad it out until it's big enough:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> n, N = 1000, 20000
>>> points = {(randint(0, n), randint(0, n)) for i in xrange(N)}
>>> while len(points) < N:
...     points |= {(randint(0, n), randint(0, n))}
...     
>>> points = list(list(x) for x in points)
```

Your initial idea was probably slow because it was iterating lists for checking containmentship, which is *O(n)*.  This uses sets which are faster, and then only converts to the list structure once at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import itertools
x = range(0,10)
aList =[]
for pair in itertools.combinations(x,2):
    for i in range(0,10):
        aList.append(pair)
print aList
```

If you want point between 0-10 with all unique and stored in a list, 
or you You need it random order, then use some random function .

Comment: It simple approach as per your question  .Your response will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since `n = 1001` is relatively small in your case, [`random.sample(population, k)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) will do just fine, taking a random sample of 20000 pairs from the space of possible pairs (no duplicates):

```
import random
print random.sample([[x, y] for x in xrange(1001) for y in xrange(1001)], 20000)
```

This is the most concise and readable solution. (But if `n` is very big, generating the entire space of points will not be computationally efficient.)

Answer (score 0):

An approach that avoids `while` loops with unknown iteration counts and avoids storing huge `list`s in memory is to use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to produce unique encoded values from a single `range` (in Py3) or `xrange` (in Py2) to avoid actually generating huge temporaries; a simple mathematical operation can split the "encoded" values back into two values:

```
import random
xys = random.sample(range(1001 * 1001), 20000)
[divmod(xy, 1001) for xy in xys] # Wrap divmod in list() if you must have list, not tuple
```