# Can I print values with no repetition in array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, repeat

```
a = [5,7,3,1,2]
for i in a:
    for j in a:
        if(i==j):
            continue
        else:
            print(i,j)
    print("")
```

output:

```
5 7
5 3
5 1
5 2

7 5
7 3
7 1
7 2

3 5
3 7
3 1
3 2

1 5
1 7
1 3
1 2

2 5
2 7
2 3
2 1
```

My code just displays all the values but will skip the values which matches but if I want dont want to display values which are printed already like if value (5,7) is printed it should not print again as (7,5). Once value 5 7 is printed so for next iteration it should not display 7 5 and this should happen with all values in array. Please someone help me. Thank you. If there is duplication of question please guide me to that question.

Comment: Could you please add expected output as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The pythonic way to generate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499327/the-pythonic-way-to-generate-pairs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Comment: No it is not duplicate my question is different from others please read it carefully

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest is to use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) which takes care of avoiding repetitions for you:

```
from itertools import combinations
a = [5, 7, 3, 1, 2]
for x, y in combinations(a, 2):
    print(x, y)

5 7
5 3
5 1
5 2
7 3
7 1
7 2
3 1
3 2
1 2
```

If you want to do it without library help, you can do the following, using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and slicing:

```
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    for y in a[i+1:]:  # combine only with elements after x (index i)
        print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) form `itertools`:

```
from itertools import combinations
for tup in combinations([5,7,3,1,2],2):
    print(tup[0],tup[1])
5 7
5 3
5 1
5 2
7 3
7 1
7 2
3 1
3 2
1 2
```

Comment: ohh thank you very much that really worked thanks for the answer

Comment: @ShivamDalvi Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
Try following:

```
a = [5,7,3,1,2]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in a[i:]:
        if(a[i]==j):
            continue
        else:
            print(a[i],j)
    print("")
```

This will give output:

```
5 7
5 3
5 1
5 2

7 3
7 1
7 2

3 1
3 2

1 2
```